# How do I properly use generics for an entity and key for a data access object

Tags: go, generics

I am very new to generics in Go and am trying to implement a basic entity and data access object with the idea that the entity has a type `E` and a key of type `K`.  The type `E` is also constrained as a model type having a field of ID of type `K`.

**template.go**

```golang
type Model[K any] struct {
    ID K
}

type CrudTemplate[E Model[K], K any] struct {
}

func (c *CrudTemplate[E, K]) FindById(ctx context.Context, id K) (*E, error) {

    tx := getTx(ctx)

    e := &E{}
    tx = tx.Find(e, id)

    if tx.Error != nil {
        return nil, tx.Error
    } else {
        return e, nil
    }
}
```

When I try and do an implementation and test as follows...

**user.go**

```golang
type User struct {
    Model[uuid.UUID]
    RealmID    uuid.UUID
    FamilyName string
    GivenName  string
}

type UserRepository struct {
    CrudTemplate[User, uuid.UUID]
}
```

... and the following test ...

**user_test.go**

```golang
func TestUserRepositoryImpl_Find(t *testing.T) {

    unit := &UserRepositoryImpl{}

    unit.FindById(ctx, id)

}
```

... it fails compilation with the following message.

> Cannot use model.User as the type interface{} Type does not implement constraint 'interface{}' because type is not included in type set ('{Model[K], {E -> model.User, K -> uuid.UUID}}')

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share UserRepositoryImpl? I am struggling to see what you intend to do defining Model the way you have defined it

Comment: Those are the complete contents of UserRepositoryImpl.  There are no additional functions using it as a receiver.

Comment: Which contents? You did not mention UserRepositoryImpl until user_test. Asking because CrudTemplate contains a getTx that seems quite implementation dependent, but as it stands right now it is not generic at all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than embedding a `struct` - I think you simply want an `interface` that your repository will implement.

To begin your `CRUD` operations, the generic read (lookup) method would look something like this:

```
type Repository[K, E any] interface {
    Find(context.Context, K) (E, error)        // search repo by key
}
```

A particular implementation of this interface:

```
type UserRepository struct {
    // ... db details
}

func (ur *UserRepository) Find(ctx context.Context, id uuid.UUID) (User, error) {
    return User{
        RealmID:    id,
        FamilyName: "Smith",
        GivenName:  "Bib",
    }, nil
}
```

And to use:

```
var ur Repository[uuid.UUID, User] // type instantiate `Repository`

ur = &UserRepository{}

u, err := ur.Find(ctx, uuid.UUID{1, 2, 3})
```

---

Working example: https://go.dev/play/p/j9cN8vy9675